# How does one prevent duplicate listings on ebay when running AddItem simultaneously?

Tags: php, ebay-api

I have a little big problem when it comes to adding listings on eBay via the API.
Currently I'm running my "Add"-script (that uses AddFixedPriceItem and picks 20 Items) 4 times each 2nd Minute.
To prevent duplicates I set an according script-id to each entry in the Database but sometimes there are still duplicates on eBay even though they're all unique entries.

Now I was thinking about UUIDs created from the title like:

```
$uuid = md5($title);
```

but is this even a good practice?
I read that UUIDs should be randomly created and only used one time. Is this true?
Maybe you also ran into such a problem and found a solution.

Comment: A UUID is a Universally Unique Identifier. These are supposed to be unique even across several platforms and timezones. There are UUID generators that can generate UUIDs for  you in many platforms. if you use a title, and in the furture get another product with the same title you will also have a conflict (and thus this is just a UID not a UUID)

Comment: If I would put various parameters like the corresponding Item Group and the ID from the entry than it should be fairly unique right?
Mainly I want to ask if i can use a UUID multiple times instead of always generating a new one.

Comment: It should. I was just pointing out that you are referencing one mechanism but using another. Hashing fields you would consider part of a congregate key that is unique in your case is fine.

Comment: have you considered testing with something in the title to see if you are accidentally pushing more than once to the API?

Answer (score 1):

For unique ID we have function [`uniqid()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) in PHP. It is based on current time in microseconds, so it's a very small chance you would have duplicates.

```
print(uniqid('ebay_')); //ebay_5f74620070891
```

Comment: I also looked into that function and tried it but I always generated a new one in the Add-Script and I still do but with the md5-function. The one thing I ask myself is if it is safe to set a UUID once and use it continuously.